# how to animate jqplot bar chart like example

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

Has anyone had any luck with this?

I copied and pasted the **exact** example code here http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html into my text editor.  I added all the .js files and .css file required.  when I run the page in any browser, I am not seeing the bars or the animation.  I have looked at the source code on the above URL as well to see how it works.  Could someone tell me why I can the animated bar chart on the URL but not from my desktop?  What's different?  Here is the exact code I copied:

```
<html>
 <title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.jqplot.min.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
        var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
        var ticks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

        plot1 =  $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
            // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
            animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: { show: true }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: ticks
                }
            },
            highlighter: { show: false }
        });

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
            }
        );
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart1" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 20px;width: 300px; height: 300px; position: relative;"></div>


<div><span>Moused Over: </span><span id="info1">Nothing</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is what I see in the browser after running that code:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested, I've found the answer.  The example code taken from the [barchart.html page](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html#) in my post doesn't appear to need the conditional syntax (below) in order to animate the bars:

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

// Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
```

From the animate example on the [examples page](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/) , the following code will do the trick:

```
animate: true,
    // Will animate plot on calls to plot1.replot({resetAxes:true})
    animateReplot: true,
```

I read the entire documentation and was doing a lot of playing around with the code. Eventually, I got to the full "examples" page (not the few listed on the [tests and examples page](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/) which I initially viewed since it was listed first in the documentation). I really wanted to understand the plugin code since the developer took so much time to really provide a ton of info, comments and updates to his code base.